# Is the sentence below correct

Tags: grammar

Food shortage is the most challenging among all problems in Africa

What if I change **among** to **of**, do they have the same meaning?

Comment: Please show you effort first, such as a grammar tutorial, example sentences.

Comment: "The most challenging of..." would be the usual way to say it.